# Regex to identify standalone numbers

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I've got a string that may or may not contain numbers. If there is a number, it will be standalone like '3200 Fedex FL' or '10 Downing St' or as part of a name like '4th ST NW' or 'I96' or 'US28'. I'm looking for a regex that will ignore the standalone numbers and give me the rest of the string but will keep the numbers as part of the name

Tried

```
Function getAddress(addr As String)  
Dim allMatches As Object  
Dim RE As Object  
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")  
RE.Pattern = "(\b[\d]+\b)"   
RE.Global = True  
RE.IgnoreCase = True 

Set allMatches = RE.Execute(addr)

If (allMatches.Count <> 0) Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If
getAddress = result
End Function
```

Example Dataset

0 I64 EB MM 93
1519  KINGSCROSS RD
28 VA288 298
JOHN RANDOLPH RD
4700 WALMSLEY BL
BOWLING GREEN  RD  / BOB WHITE RD
BRUCE CT /FLORIDA AV
BUCK RD AND WHITEHALL RD
DOWNTOWN EWRESSWY EB  2ND ST
HYHLAND VISTA  / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
HYHLAND VISTA  / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
HYHLAND VISTA DR  / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
I95 25 43
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD  /CLARENCE RD
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD  /CLARENCE RD
NOVAH HOWARD   ST /SEMINARY RD
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD  R COUVAHOUSE RD
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD  R COUVAHOUSE RD
WOODLAND AND ROANOKE
1501 SAMS CR1
15281 WHITEHEAD RD
1532 MARLBORO ST
16907 BRANDERS BRIDGE RD
1750 WILLIAM ST

Expected Output:
I64 EB MM
KINGSCROSS RD
VA288
JOHN RANDOLPH RD
BOWLING GREEN RD / BOB WHITE RD
BRUCE CT /FLORIDA AV
BUCK RD AND WHITEHALL RD
DOWNTOWN EWRESSWY EB 2ND ST
HYHLAND VISTA / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
HYHLAND VISTA / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
HYHLAND VISTA DR / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL
I95
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD /CLARENCE RD
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD /CLARENCE RD
NOVAH HOWARD ST /SEMINARY RD
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD R COUVAHOUSE RD
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD R COUVAHOUSE RD
WOODLAND AND ROANOKE
SAMS CR1
WHITEHEAD RD
MARLBORO ST
BRANDERS BRIDGE RD
WILLIAM ST

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work?

Comment: Please post a **clear** sample of the **input** and desired **output**

Comment: in your "part of a name" example `US 28` the numbers `28` are standalone... or are you looking for standalone numbers at the start of the string?

Comment: @Vallentin I tried '^[0-9]*$' , but this is just for the first word

Comment: @PedroLobito Posted it.

Comment: @JordanDavis Fixed it, was a typo

Comment: Remove the `^` and `$` from your regex so it can match anywhere in the string. Add `\b` to only match stand-alone: `\b\d+\b` and replace with empty string.

Comment: @Cyclops cool got you now

Comment: @trincot I arrived at the same conclusion at the exact very moment and updated my post but that is the exact opposite of what I want.

Comment: It is not the opposite if you use that regex to determine what to *delete* from the string.

Comment: @trincot It will give me what to delete, that is fine but I have 100,000+ rows and I want to keep the string barring these instances.

Comment: But you just need to replace with the empty string... See the substitute panel in [this regex test](https://regex101.com/r/ixUBc5/2). Isn't that the result you need?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @trincot. That is exactly what I want. How can i get the substitute panel info in a csv file?

Comment: That depends on which language you are using... Please read the usage description of the `regex` tag: *"all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool"*

Comment: @trincot I am using VB with excel, I have uploaded the code I am using.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx) method of the `RegExp` object:

```
RE.Global = True   
RE.Pattern = "\b\d+(\s|$)"
result = RE.Replace(addr, "") ' Remove all matches from string
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
(?![0-9]+\s).
```

It looks for consecutive numbers followed by a space and negates them

Comment: But it would not work for cases like "I95", "US28" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be easier match standalone numbers and replace them with empty string. The standalone numbers regex (with surrounding spaces) is

```
\s*\b\d+\b\s*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/JuEAQd/1

*Note: the output result in the demo above is a little bet mixed up because all test strings put in one input but when taken one by one, the [result](https://regex101.com/r/cvwUzQ/1) [is](https://regex101.com/r/g07lGg/1) [fine](https://regex101.com/r/XC1CLR/1).*

Comment: This selects the numbers, not the string. How would I make the selection the exact opposite?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the pattern you want (match letters followed by number + rest of word or match numbers followed by letter followed by rest of word)

```
/\b([A-z]+[0-9]+[A-z0-9]*|[0-9]+[A-z]+[A-z0-9]*)\b/gm
```

and in action...

```js
var pattern = /\b([A-z]+[0-9]+[A-z0-9]*|[0-9]+[A-z]+[A-z0-9]*)\b/gm
var str = "0 I64 EB MM 93\
1519 KINGSCROSS RD\
28 VA288 298\
JOHN RANDOLPH RD\
4700 WALMSLEY BL\
BOWLING GREEN RD / BOB WHITE RD\
BRUCE CT /FLORIDA AV\
BUCK RD AND WHITEHALL RD\
DOWNTOWN EWRESSWY EB 2ND ST\
HYHLAND VISTA / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL\
HYHLAND VISTA / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL\
HYHLAND VISTA DR / GEORGE WASHINGTON BL\
I95 25 43\
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD /CLARENCE RD\
LAUARL RIDGE MILL RD /CLARENCE RD\
NOVAH HOWARD ST /SEMINARY RD\
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD R COUVAHOUSE RD\
OLD COUVAHOUSE RD R COUVAHOUSE RD\
WOODLAND AND ROANOKE\
1501 SAMS CR1\
15281 WHITEHEAD RD\
1532 MARLBORO ST\
16907 BRANDERS BRIDGE RD\
1750 WILLIAM ST"
console.log(str.match(pattern))
```

Comment: This works upto a point but it ignores the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the programming language you're using, but you need to `replace` **not simply match**, something like:

for `python`:

```
import re
new_text = re.sub(r" ?\b\d+\b ?", "", old_text)
```

for `php`:

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/ ?\b\d+\b ?/', '', $old_text);
```

for `vb` (.NET):

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    Dim RegexObj As New Regex(" ?\b\d+\b ?")
    ResultString = RegexObj.Replace(SubjectString, "")
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

---

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m70xeQ/2)